# NPE in ResteasyServletInitializer

Tags: jakarta-ee, jetty, jax-rs, resteasy

When deploying my war to Jetty 8.1+ (Servlet 3.0) i get the following stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.servlet.ResteasyServletInitializer.onStartup(ResteasyServletInitializer.java:55)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:106)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializerListener.doStart(ServletContainerInitializerListener.java:107)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
>           at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)

web.xml is empty. There is one Application Class like:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/appPath")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
}
```

why is there a NPE being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

For me the reason was that the MyApplication Class was sitting in the default package (don't ask why, clumsy while creating it in the IDE).

Moving it to a package instantly resolved the problem.